# Doubt on a certain asymptotic formula

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, asymptotics

Suppose that $f \colon [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is a function such that
the formula

$$f(x) = \frac{\pi(x)}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}\log_{2}x}} \left(e^{-\frac{(k-0.5\log_{2} x)^{2}}{0.5 \log_{2}x}}+\mathcal{O} ((\log x)^{-0.5 +\varepsilon})\right)$$

is said to hold uniformly for all integers $k\geq 0$ and any given $\varepsilon>0$. (As usual, $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes in the interval $[1,x]$.)

Is it possible to deduce from such a formula that if $k$ is sufficiently large then $f(x)\geq 1$ for infinitely many $x$'s? In the affirmative case, how easy was it for you to see what the answer was?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to leave your observations or answers.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)\geq 1$ asymptotically, or at some particular value, or for all $x$? (Or is that supposed to be 'if $x$ is sufficiently large'?)

Comment: You are right, I needed to be a little more specific in that regard.

Comment: Having gone though the analysis, the $\exp(-\frac{k-c\lg x)^2}{c\lg x})$ term is (as noted in some comments) dwarfed by the $O((\log x)^{-1/2})$ term, so it's not clear that anything meaningful can be said about $f$'s growth (except that it's fairly slow); for instance, $f(x)$ identically zero would appear to satisfy the relation for all $k$ and any $\epsilon$.