# Flawed proof that $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln{n}(\ln{(\ln{n})})}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

My proof:

If $\ n \ge 25$, then $$ \frac{1}{n\ln{n}(\ln{(\ln{n})})} \le \frac{1}{n(\ln{n})^{1.1}}$$.

Since $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \ \frac{1}{n(\ln{n})^{p}}$$
converges when $p \gt 1$.

It follows that $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln{n}(\ln{(\ln{n})})}$$ also converges.

I know this series is supposed to diverge and therefore my proof is flawed by I can't see where exactly I'm going wrong.

I think it's the first inequality that is the problem given that I obtained it using Mathematica and didn't actually proof it.

Comment: You DID NOT obtain that inequality from Mathematica for all $n\geq 25$.

Comment: Why the downvote? You present this problem to the average Calc 2 student with the message "Find the mistake" and I bet half of them won't find it.

Comment: You are right the first inequality is definitely wrong as $\ln (n)^{1.1}$ is asymptotically greater than $\ln (n) \cdot \ln (\ln (n))$

Comment: @imranfat And those who found the mistake won't be able to explain why it is wrong.

Comment: @Yanko Why is it not possible to explain it's wrong (or is it too high level)?

Comment: Since  $\ln(n)=o(n^p)$ for any $p>0$, $\ln(n) \le K n^{0.1}$ for some positive $K \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $n \ge 1$. Hence $\ln(n) \ln(\ln(n)) \le k \ln(n) \ln(n)^{0.1} = k \ln(n)^{1.1}$.

Comment: your proof contains some number that is not easy to verify without a computer. just use integral test, hints given by @will jagy

Comment: Similar non-example would be that $\sum \frac1{n^p}$ converges when $p>1$ but $\frac1{n\ln n}\leq\frac1{n^{1.1}}$ which is false for large enough $n$ (also the series $\sum \frac1{n\ln n}$ diverges).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/280257/321264.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've forgotten to invert the direction of inequality in your proof. It is *not* the case that if $a\leq b$ then $\frac1a\leq\frac1b$; in fact, (assuming all numbers involved are positive) the opposite holds: $a\leq b\implies \frac1a\geq\frac1b$. In this case, since $\ln(\ln n)\leq (\ln n)^{0.1}$, we have $\displaystyle\frac1{\ln\ln n}\geq \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{0.1}}$ and thus $\displaystyle\frac1{n(\ln n)(\ln\ln n)}\geq\frac1{n(\ln n)^{1.1}}$. But being termwise greater than the terms of a convergent series tells us nothing about the convergence of the series we're interested in.

Comment: Nice answer, and thank you for actually answering the question being asked instead of presenting other proofs that the series diverges.

Comment: +1 I also overlooked this relatively simple thing about reciprocals. Madness!

Comment: @imranfat I made this exact same mistake in disguise [in analyzing an asymptotic formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671237/doubt-on-a-certain-asymptotic-formula), so I suspect I was primed to spot it here. It's surprisingly easy to miss!

Answer (score 1):

Using logarithms base $e,$ what is the derivative of
$$  f(x) = \log \log \log x \; \; ?  $$
In case of doubt, this means
$$  f(x) = \log \left( \log \left(  \log x \right) \right)  $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that by [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

$$ 0 \ \leq\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)\ \leq\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n}f(2^{n})\ \leq\ 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$$

thus

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n\ln{n}\cdot(\ln{(\ln{n})})} \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{2^n\cdot\ln2^n \cdot\ln (\ln 2^n)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln 2\cdot\ln(n\ln 2)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n\ln 2(\ln n+\ln\ln2)}=+\infty$$

indeed

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac2{n\ln 2(\ln n+\ln\ln2)}\ge\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{2^n\ln 2(\ln2^n+\ln\ln2)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln^22+\ln2\cdot\ln\ln2}=+\infty$$

Comment: Where does the first inequality come from? This is certainly _not_ true if, say, $n\gt e^{e^2}$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki is not $log x <le x$?

Comment: Yes, but $(\ln n)(\ln n)\neq\ln(n^2)$.

Comment: Oh I've interpreted it as $\ln(n\ln(\ln n)))$!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I've revised by Cauchy condensation test

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Something wrong again?

Answer (score 1):

> If  n≥25, then
>
> $\frac{1}{n\ln{n}(\ln{(\ln{n})})} \le \frac{1}{n(\ln{n})^{1.1}}$

---

this estimation might not be sharp enough. that could be the flaw in your proof. @will gagy provided elegant solution, which is integral test.